# Coin flipping game - expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given a weighted coin that lands on heads 55% of the time, you flip the coin until you get you get your first tails. For each heads, you make \$1. When you flip tails you lose \$0.90. What is the expected value of this game?

So far I have come up with the following: Let $X$ be a random variable that takes value 1 with probability 0.55 and -0.90 with probability 0.45. Then $E[X] = 1 \times 0.55 - (0.45 \times 0.90) = 0.145$. I have no idea if this is correct or not though? Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to Shubham Johri's, giving the same answer

- If you get a heads, you receive $\$1$ and get to flip again
- If you get a tails, you pay $\$0.90$ and stop
- So $E[X]=0.55 \times (1+E[X]) +0.45\times (-0.90)$
- Giving $E[X] = \frac{0.55 - 0.45\times 0.90}{1-0.55} = \frac{29}{90} \approx \$0.32$

Comment: Hello Henry, why do you do $...\times (1+E[X])$, I don't understand the adding the expected value part.

Comment: @Sarah the "$1+E[X]$" is "if you get a heads, you receive $\$1$ and get to flip again", since if you start again your expectation is then $E[X]$

Comment: Hi Henry thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider getting a tails as a success and getting heads a failure, then the probability distribution of $r$ failures followed by one success is a [geometric distribution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/geometric-distribution/) with probability of success $p=P(\text{tails})=0.45$.

Let $X$ denote this random variable giving the number of failures before the first success. Then the value of the game is given by $X-0.90$, since each failure awards $\$1$ and the final success takes away $\$0.90$. Then the expected value is given by$$E[X-0.90]=E[X]-0.90=\frac{0.55}{0.45}-0.90\approx0.32$$

---

Alternatively, note that the value earned on getting $x$ heads followed by one tails is $x-0.90$. The probability of getting $x$ heads consecutively and then one tails is $0.55^x(0.45)$. The expected value is$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty(x-0.90)\cdot0.45\cdot(0.55)^x$$

Comment: The expression at the end of your post is flawed. Try computing it and you will see that you do not get the correct result.

Comment: @Math1000 It [matches](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=29c546473e1c796d6076bb18901b15e7&title=Infinite%20Series%20Calculator&theme=blue&i0=0.45*(n-0.9)*(0.55)%5En&i1=0&i2=Infinity&podSelect=&includepodid=Result&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1) my first answer.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I converted the decimals into fractions incorrectly. Never mind then.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Hello, can you explain why $E[x] = \frac{0.55}{0.45}$ in your first answer? Thanks.

Comment: @SarahV.P The expectation of a geometric distribution is $(1-p)/p$ (you can find this info in the embedded link).